# Android edittext: Formatting number

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, format, string-formatting

I have a `edittext`, and  if I enter input number as `100000`, the result must be `100.000`, and if I enter input as `1000000`, the result must be `1.000.000`.

After every 3 characters from the last to beginning must have a  "`.`"

Here is my code:

```
tambah = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.total);
tambah.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){
       public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
              // ...
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something I use to for dollar input. It makes sure that there are only 2 places past the decimal point at all times. You should be able to adapt it to your needs by removing the $ sign.

```
amountEditText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if(!s.toString().matches("^\\$(\\d{1,3}(\\,\\d{3})*|(\\d+))(\\.\\d{2})?$"))
    {
        String userInput= ""+s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
        StringBuilder cashAmountBuilder = new StringBuilder(userInput);

        while (cashAmountBuilder.length() > 3 && cashAmountBuilder.charAt(0) == '0') {
            cashAmountBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);
        }
        while (cashAmountBuilder.length() < 3) {
            cashAmountBuilder.insert(0, '0');
        }
        cashAmountBuilder.insert(cashAmountBuilder.length()-2, '.');
        cashAmountBuilder.insert(0, '$');

        amountEditText.setText(cashAmountBuilder.toString());
        // keeps the cursor always to the right
        Selection.setSelection(amountEditText.getText(), cashAmountBuilder.toString().length());

    }

}
});
```

Comment: i use 2 place u can set 3 place

Comment: always welcome dude just try it once i hope it will work for u :)

Comment: i'm beginner in android, i want to ask, what function of : if(!s.toString().matches("^\\$(\\d{1,3}(\\,\\d{3})*|(\\d+))(\\.\\d{2})?$"))

Comment: its a regular expression dude

Comment: read more about on this http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Can you share the code for 3 digits after decimal

Answer (score 0):

You should use ['java.text.NumberFormat'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html):

```
java.text.NumberFormat nf = java.text.NumberFormat.getInstane();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
String formattedNumber = nf.format(Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText());
```

Comment: yes, you are right, but i need a logic to format String like that

Answer (score 0):

Use editText.setOnTextChangeListener()  and  check every time if the position is of multiple of 3 put a .(dot) there..

Comment: give me full logic, help me please.

Comment: check position % 3 == 0

Comment: i thinks, there is no event setOnTextChangeListener() on edittext

Answer (score 0):

At first format your string with `%,d` format then replace all (,) with (.) as follows...

```
    String formatedString = (String.format("%,d", 1000000)).replace(',', '.');

    Log.d("Fomated String", formatedString);
```

**Output:**

```
 D/Fomated String(20323): 1.000.000
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it with following loop.

```
String Number=1000000;
final int THREE=3;
int noOfPoints,length,Start=0,End=0;

length=Number.length();
noOfPoints=length%THREE;
if(noOfPoints*THREE==length)
noOfPoints--;
String OutPut="";

for(int Count=0;Count<=noOfPoints;Count++)
{
Start=End;
if(Count==0)
End=length-(THREE*noOfPoints);
else
End=Start+THREE;

if(Count!=noOfPoints)
OutPut+=Number.substring(Start,End)+".";
else
OutPut+=Number.substring(Start,End);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another answer. hope it helps, simple and it would format the size for given params(formatsize, loook at the sample calls)
take a look.

/**
 * 
 * @param input
 * @param formatsize
 * @return
 */

```
public String format(String input, int formatsize) {

    String formattedNumberString = "";
    int len = input.length();

    if (len < formatsize)
        return input;

    if (formatsize < 2) {
        System.out.println("Opppps");
        return "";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += formatsize) {
        if (i < formatsize) {
            formattedNumberString = input.substring(input.length()
                    - formatsize - 1, input.length() - 1);
        } else {

            if (len - i <= formatsize) {
                formattedNumberString = input + "." + formattedNumberString;
            } else {
                formattedNumberString = input.substring(input.length()
                        - formatsize - 1, input.length() - 1)
                        + "." + formattedNumberString;
            }
        }

        if (input.length() >= formatsize)
            input = input.substring(0, len - i - formatsize);
    }

    return formattedNumberString;
}
```

call this function like.. (e.g.)

```
NumberFormatterClass nfc = new NumberFormatterClass();
System.out.println(nfc.format("1032432420000000000000", 3));
System.out.println(nfc.format("1032432420000000000000", 4));
System.out.println(nfc.format("1032432420000000000000", 5));
System.out.println(nfc.format("1032432420000000000000", 2));
```

regards...